# Best package to use for network communication in Android.. Java/Apache?

Tags: java, android, apache, sockets

I am trying to accomplish the following tasks:

1. Connect to an existing server using the Android app as a client.
2. Keep the connection alive sending and receiving yada yada, the normal keep-alive session.
3. (Difficult part) I need to (as close to real-time as possible) detect a socket break on the client side.

Should I use the Apache net package or Java net package? Any other hints on how to accomplish #3 is also appreciated.  Which package offers the best performance/usability for use in Android applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a project I made once (Android app and Java server), I used the very powerful [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) framework. It enabled me to implement a protocol once and share the code between the server and the app.

It may be a bit overkill depending on your needs, but it allows for very efficient and scalable network applications.

Comment: I've been playing around with it for a couple hours now and the simple handler ive created is notifying me on disconnects. Thanks for this!!